# Petición POST HTTPS contra API REST desde Android Studio

Tags: java, android, post, https

Estoy intentando realizar una petición `POST` desde `Android` contra un web service `REST`.

Utilizo la clase `HttpsURLConnection` pero una vez abierta la conexión no se como realizar la petición. Encontré cosas sobre el `okHttpClient` pero no se como utlizarlo.

Tengo esto:

```
        new SSLTrustManager();
        HttpsURLConnection connection = ConfigConnect.getServerConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(ConfigConnect.getTimeout());
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.connect();



        Log.e("INFO", "LA CONEXIÓN SE HA HECHO, PROCEDEMOS A MONTAR EL CUERPO DE LA PETICIÓN Y MANDARLA");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.authkey), mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.authmoduleval1));
        jsonObject.put(mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.userkey), mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.userval));
        jsonObject.put(mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.passkey), mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.passval));
        jsonObject.put(mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.latitude), String.valueOf(latitud));
        jsonObject.put(mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.longitude), String.valueOf(longitud));

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        byte[] input = jsonObject.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
```

Me da error en la línea `connection.connect()`:

> 06-11 15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 06-11 15:45:35.480
>   23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1285)
>   06-11 15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110) 06-11
>   15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:154) 06-11 15:45:35.480
>   23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122) 06-11 15:45:35.480
>   23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) 06-11
>   15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452) 06-11
>   15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:944) 06-11 15:45:35.480
>   23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
>   06-11 15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
>   06-11 15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:79)
>   06-11 15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) 06-11
>   15:45:35.480 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.altrockstech.disashopsnapshot.webService.PeticionesWS.autenticar(PeticionesWS.java:85)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.altrockstech.disashopsnapshot.webService.PeticionesWS.onReceive(PeticionesWS.java:40)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2788)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:168) 06-11
>   15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1456)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 06-11
>   15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 06-11 15:45:35.481
>   23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665) 06-11
>   15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 06-11 15:45:35.481
>   23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
>   06-11 15:45:35.481 23394-23394/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de realizar la conexión,

```
connection.connect();
```

Agrega un `BufferedReader` para obtener los datos obtenidos por la petición y mediante un `StringBuffer` almacenas cada linea obtenida en la petición:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Respuesta obtenida: " + response.toString());
```

---

Para agregar parametros a tu petición puedes crear un Json :

```
String jsonParametros = "{"nombre": "Laura", "ocupacion": "programador"}";
```

Y lo escribimos:

```
try(OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    byte[] input = jsonParametros.getBytes("utf-8");
    os.write(input, 0, input.length);           
}
```

Revisa:

https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post

Comment: y como puedo meter el cuerpo en la petición POST?

Comment: Agrego actualización.

Comment: Agrego actualización